# Error 500 IIS get ajax.php

Tags: php, iis

I encountered the following problem I am using the server with apache IIS and I'm getting error in response request via get

webconfig:

```
                <rule name="Imported Rule 15" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^aj/([^/.]+)/?$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="ajax.php?type={R:1}&amp;first={R:2}"  />
            </rule>

            <rule name="Imported Rule 16" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^aj/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="ajax.php?type={R:1}&amp;first={R:2}" appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Imported Rule 17" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^aj/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="ajax.php?type={R:1}&amp;first={R:2}&amp;second={R:3}" appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule>
```

I tried to fix several methods as close as I got to it by changing the `ajax.php?type={R:1}&amp;first={R:2}` para `ajax.php?type={R:1}&amp;`
I can't make this upload system working, what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Why do you think it's a problem with the webconfig and not with your php code?

Comment: because I already left the ajax.php file blank and continue with error 500

Comment: Describe your environment and the "problem/error" clearly. Nobody can see your screen but you.

Comment: the page at the moment is without any code
and even then the error continues and only disappears when I remove webconfig but I need webconfig to make the requests

Comment: GET http://filmesonlinehd.in/aj/get_notifications?hash=f91f1f1b73365a42a7214c522a961810e4cdb30a&t=new 500 (URL Rewrite Module Error.)